# Retriving values from Item Clicked in Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-listview

I have implement Custom List in which i have stored data -> class->Hash Map->List->Adapter.It Places data successfully and shows me list.But when i click on Item in list.I am unable to retrieve clicked value.my code is

```
public class asasa extends Activity  {
    //ListView listView;
    Intent intent;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //Class Declartion DataHolder
    DataHolder obj;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";

    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";           
    private static final String TAG_Description = "description";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "url";
    private static final String TAG_Price = "price";
    private static final String TAG_class = "DataHolider";


    LazyAdapter adapter;
    // flag for Internet connection status
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

    // products JSONArray

    JSONArray products = null;

    // Connection detector class
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sportsList);
        l1.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, image));
         */

        // creating connection detector class instance
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            LoadAllProducts il = new LoadAllProducts();
            il.execute(URL);
        }
        else
        {
            // Internet connection is not present
            // Ask user to connect to Internet
            Toast.makeText(asasa.this, "No Internet Connection You don't have internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



    }
    public void longToast(CharSequence message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private  LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Object>> data;
        //public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
        int i=0;
        public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Object>> d) {
            activity = a;
            data=d;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
            TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
            TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
            ImageView imageview=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            //ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

            HashMap<Integer, Object> song = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
            song = data.get(position);

             DataHolder objj=new DataHolder();
            objj=(DataHolder) song.get(position);

            Log.i("iiiiii  "," " +i++);

            Log.i("objj.GetName()  ",objj.GetName());
            Log.i("objj.GetDescription()  ",objj.GetDescription());
            Log.i("objj.GetPrice()  ",objj.GetPrice());


            title.setText(objj.GetName());
            artist.setText(objj.GetDescription());
            duration.setText(objj.GetPrice());
            imageview.setImageBitmap(objj.Getimage());

            //imageLoader.

            return vi;
        }
    }






    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        // creating new HashMap
            ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Object>> productsList=new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,Object>>();
            Bitmap decodedByte;



        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(asasa.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            //Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                    Log.i("products  ",products.toString());
                    // looping through All Products
                    Log.i("LENGTHHHH  "," "+products.length());
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("ccccccccc  ",c.toString());
                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        //  String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        Log.i("name::",name);

                        String description = c.getString(TAG_Description);
                        Log.i("description::",description);

                        /*String URl = c.getString(TAG_URL);
                        Log.i("URl",URl);
*/
                        String price = c.getString(TAG_Price);
                        Log.i("price",price);

                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(c.getString(TAG_URL), Base64.DEFAULT);
                         decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 

                         obj=new DataHolder();
                         obj.setData(name, description, price, decodedByte);


                            HashMap<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();



                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(i, obj);
                        /*map.put(TAG_Description, description);
                        map.put(TAG_URL, decodedByte);
                        map.put(TAG_Price, price);*/
                        //Log.i("MAP",map.toString());
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList

                        productsList.add(map);

                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    /*Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);*/
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            ListView list;

            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

            // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            //adapter=new LazyAdapter(a, d)
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(asasa.this, productsList);        
            list.setAdapter(adapter);


            // Click event for single list row
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                Log.i("Name---------------"," "+    productsList.get(view.getId()).get(position).getClass().getName());
                }
            });     

            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            }


    }

    }
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();


    }


public class DataHolder 

{
    String Name;
    String Description;
    String Price;
    Bitmap image;

    public void setData(String Name,String Descipton,String Price,Bitmap iamage)
    {
         this.Name=Name;
         this.Description=Descipton;
         this.Price=Price;
         this.image=iamage;
    }

    public String GetName()
    {return Name;}
    public String GetDescription()
    {return Description;}
    public String GetPrice()
    {return Price;}
    public Bitmap Getimage()
    {return image;}

}





}
```

i want help in this part of code

```
    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
        Log.i("Name---------------"," "+    productsList.get(view.getId()).get(position).getClass().getName());
        }
    });
```

**Q2:why GetView is called infinitely at back-end though list is displayed successfully**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i HAVE SOLVED MY PROBLEM THIS WAY

```
HashMap<String, Object> item = productsList.get(position);
DataHolder Data= new DataHolder();
Data= (DataHolder) item.get(ITEMTITLE);
Log.i("productsListID  ", Data.Get_Id())

;
```